# Comparing two sets A and B and need to process A - B, B - A, and A intersects B

Tags: c#, linq, set

I have two sets **A** and **B** that I need to compare.  I need to do processing for

- A intersects B (the elements that are the same)
- A - B (elements in A that are not in B), and
- B - A (elements in B that are not in A).

Approaches I've considered:

1. I could use the algorithm [described here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/10042) (and pasted below), and do my processing in-line.  This is nice because it only iterates through the elements in each set once.

   > ```
   > Given input sets A,B, each a strictly ascending list. 
   > Initialize A\B and B\A as empty lists.
   >
   > Until A or B is empty, compare the heads of both lists
   >     If the heads are equal, remove them.
   >     If the head of A preceeds the head of B, remove the head from A
   >        and include it in A\B.
   >     If the head of B preceeds the head of A, remove the head from B
   >        and include it in B\A.
   >
   > Now A or B is empty.
   > Transfer entries left in A to A\B or entries left in B to B\A.
   > ```
2. I could do this using methods on `Hashset<T>` ([`Intersect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb918911(v=vs.90).aspx), [`ExceptWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299875(v=vs.110).aspx)) or the `Enumerable` Linq extension methods ([`Intersect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb460136(v=vs.100).aspx), [`Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb300779(v=vs.100).aspx)).  These have the advantage of making my code/intent more readable, but I would end up iterating the original sets multiple times.

**Question:**
Is there an approach where I could get the readability of option #2 with the performance of #1?

Comment: Have your option# 1 in an extension method and use that, but do some performance tests to see if your option 1 is really better than LINQ

Comment: Also, it appears the option 1 requires lists to be in sorted order.

Comment: @Habib, Have option #1 in an extension method that returns what? all three new sets as `IEnumerable` `out`parameters?  And make those returned sets deferred execution enumerables?

Comment: if your sets are not in sorted order, then sorting them would be an extra overhead. But if you have working solutions for both option then measure their execution.

Comment: you will end up with multiple extension methods, Are you trying to do all the three tasks in one method ?

Comment: @Habib, if I had multiple extension methods, I would end up iterating through the source sets multiple times, which at that point, I would just use either linq or Hashset approach.

Comment: How big are your sets? How frequently will your program do this? You should use the HashSet<T> version, until at some point you have a demonstrable performance problem. You certainly can implement #1 in a "readable" way, but only to the caller; the implementation itself will be just as complex. Note that you don't really need the precise algorithm you describe in #1. HashSet<T> access is quick (that's the point...O(1) retrieval) so you can enumerate one HashSet and correlate it against the other rather than sorting the data first.